# How to use JGit to get the whole Java file of a commit?

Tags: java, jgit

In a commit, there are some java files have been revised.
For the each revised file in a commit, I want to get the whole file content of the revised file and the previous file (before revised).
Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate your question-reviews

Comment: For example, a java file has been revised and committed to git, note as fileA, and use fileB to note the java file before revised. Then I want to get the whole content of fileA and fileB, not just the modified parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do a `RevWalk` with the commit-id and then a `TreeWalk` to get the actual file contents.

You can take a look at the example at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ReadFileFromCommit.java in my jgit-cookbook. It shows how to fetch a file for a specific commit. Just call it with your filename instead of README.md once for each of the two commit-ish instead of HEAD to get the content of the two files.

Comment: Thank you so much.